# How to define a class within a library in Lua (Love2D)?

Tags: class, module, lua, love2d

I've tried defining my class on a file called "basic.lua" called "Point" and tried to implement it on the file "main.lua" but I keep getting this error:

```
Error

Syntax error: basic.lua:3: '(' expected near 'Point'



Traceback

[C]: at 0x7ffc269728f0
[C]: in function 'require'
main.lua:3: in function 'load'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Here is my code for "basic.lua"

```
return {

  function Point(self, x, y)
    local Point = {

      x = x;
      y = y;

      AsString = function(self)
          print("{x: " + self.x + ", y: " + self.y + "}");
      end;
      
    }
    return Point;
  end;

};
```

and here is my code for "main.lua"

```
function love.load()

    local Basic = require("basic");

    PlayerAcceleration = Basic.Point:new{1, 2};
    PlayerVelocity = Basic.Point:new{0, 0};
    PlayerPosition = Basic.Point:new{0, 0};

    love.graphics.print(PlayerAcceleration.AsString(), 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

end;
```

I'm struggling with Lua's classes a lot so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your module returns a table but inside that table constructor you try to define a global function `Point`. You cannot create a table field like that. This is invalid syntax.

```
return { function a() end }
```

Use

```
return { a = function() end }
```

instead.

```
PlayerAcceleration.AsString()
```

Will not work. Either use `PlayerAcceleration.AsString(PlayerAcceleration)` or `PlayerAcceleration:AsString()`

Otherwise `AsString`'s parameter `self` will be nil leading to an error when you attempt to index it in the function's body.

`"{x: " + self.x + ", y: " + self.y + "}"` is not how you concatenate strings in Lua. Use Lua's concatenation operator `..` instead of `+`.

Further you're calling `Basic.Point:new` which does not exist. Please do a Lua beginners tutorial, read the Programming in Lua and the Lua Reference Manual befor you continue trying to implement classes.

Comment: Yeah I noticed when I drafted this, that I didn't add "AsString" onto "PlayerAcceleration" so I just chucked it on how I would with any other programming language (with a ".") and since I didn't get to debug "AsString" method, the concatenation and the constructor because the code was failing before the class was even defined I didn't even realise they were a problem. Thanks though, looks like I learnt a lot more than I originally intended to!